# Scroll Restoration does not work on firefox browser

Tags: remix.run

I'm using the remix `Link` component to route to a specific page and the scroll `restores to the top both google chrome and safari`. But it *doesn't work in firefox* browser.

```
<Link to="/contact-us">
    <button name="contactus" className="hue-btn">
      <span>CONTACT US</span>
    </button>
</Link>
```

my remix version is :  `"remix": "^2.4.1"`

I'm puzzled here How can i get it to function properly with scroll to top when routing occurs in the firefox browser?

please ask if any more details are required about this issue

Comment: This seems more like something you file an [issue](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues) for. That said, we can't help address issues in code we can't see, so if you can, please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, and provide more complete details for the issue like browser version and reproduction steps, etc. See [Help/How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for additional tips to improve the quality of your post.